# Windows Service Control - How to determine who changed the password on service account?

Tags: windows, passwords, services

On windows Service Control - How to determine who changed the password on service account ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Windows services are run under the context of a user..    this user has credentials - saved.  If the users password is changed  and the service is updated -  the service will fail to start next reboot.   Alternately - if the users password is changed on the service -  it will also fail to start when the server reboots..  I want to know who updated the services account password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How do I find out who changed a password?

Look for 4723: An attempt was made to change an account's password and 4724: An attempt was made to reset an accounts password

> **4723: An attempt was made to change an account's password**
>
> - The user attempted to change his/her own password.  Subject and Target should always match.  Don't confuse this event with 4724.
> - This event is logged as a failure if his new password fails to meet the password policy.
> - If the user fails to correctly enter his old password this event is not logged.  Instead, for domain accounts, a 4771 is logged with
>     kadmin/changepw as the service name.
> - This event is logged both for local SAM accounts and domain accounts.
> - You will also see event ID 4738 informing you of the same information.
>
> **Subject**:
>
> The user and logon session that performed the action.
>
> - Security ID:  The SID of the account.
> - Account Name: The account logon name.
> - Account Domain: The domain or - in the case of local accounts - computer name.
> - Logon ID is a semi-unique (unique between reboots) number that identifies the logon session.  Logon ID allows you to correlate
>     backwards to the logon event (4624) as well as with other events
>     logged during the same logon session.

See the source link below for a full list of Categories and Subcategories for the event.

Source [4723: An attempt was made to change an account's password](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4723)

> **4724: An attempt was made to reset an accounts password**
>
> - The Subject attempted to reset the password of the Target:
> - Don't confuse this event with 4723.
> - This event is logged as a failure if the new password fails to meet the password policy.
> - This event is logged both for local SAM accounts and domain accounts.
> - You will also see one or more event ID 4738s informing you of the same information.
>
> **Subject**:
>
> The user and logon session that performed the action.
>
> - Security ID:  The SID of the account.
> - Account Name: The account logon name.
> - Account Domain: The domain or - in the case of local accounts - computer name.
> - Logon ID is a semi-unique (unique between reboots) number that identifies the logon session.  Logon ID allows you to correlate
>     backwards to the logon event (4624) as well as with other events
>     logged during the same logon session.

See the source link below for a full list of Categories and Subcategories for the event.

Source [4724: An attempt was made to reset an accounts password](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4724)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Windows Security Log Events](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/Default.aspx?catid=2)